# Macbook eGPU to be used only for external monitors

Tags: graphics-cards, multiple-monitors, thunderbolt

I have a Macbook Pro (13 inch, two Thunderbolt 3 ports) connected to two external monitors. I'm looking to purchase a GPU to sit in an eGPU enclosure (the [AKiTiO node](https://www.akitio.com/expansion/node)) purely to be able to support more external monitors. So I don't need the GPU to be especially performant (right?), just to be able to support e.g. 4 external monitors, not of an especially high resolution.

So my questions:

- Will a Thunderbolt-3 connected eGPU really allow me to use multiple monitors through it? I know it can at least support 1 (at the cost of one thunderbolt port anyway)
- Is GPU performance really unimportant here if I'm only displaying e.g. desktop applications (e.g. text editors) on the external monitors?
- What GPU would you recommend?

Comment: Technically (as I know of) the external GPU should allow you to connect as many displays as the number of connectors it has cause you just connect one thunderbolt cable to your Laptop and thats it. Mmmm But it might affect your Framerates and Resolution depending upon your Displays. Soo Yeah it completely depemds upon your monitors which GPU you wanna choose. But as you said you wanna run just text editors so Any GPU can do that  Intels integrated GPUs can do 4k at 30FPS

Comment: So it's safe to assume that a single thunderbolt 3 cable can handle the throughput of issuing at least the desktop info (to be rendered by the GPU) of many monitors? Ok great, so it sounds like I can get away with pretty cheap! :)

Comment: TBH as of what I know You dont even need the eGPU

Comment: What exactly do you know then? Because I have the impression an eGPU is absolutely necessary to have more than 2 external displays when limited to two Thunderbolt 3 ports

Comment: Well what I know is you can simply run the two monitors easily unless they are some 5k displays. And you generally use an eGPU only when your Laptops GPU is not powerful enough.

Comment: I've stated multiple times this is for more than 2 monitors, and that my current setup (without an eGPU) is using 2

Comment: Mmm At what resolution ?

Comment: No offense, but you seem as clueless about this as I am :) See here: https://hengedocks.com/blogs/henge-docks-blog/how-to-run-external-displays-with-your-usb-c-thunderbolt-3-macbook

Comment: Yup Guess so. Anyway IDRK. I am out.